# Remove all Items in a Sass Map at once

Tags: sass

I just want to ask if there is any option to remove all items in a sass map at once.

I have for example a sass map for colors, where i put some default colors inside:

```
$colors: (
    grey: (
        base: '#ccc',
        shades: (
            light: '#eee',
            dark: '#333',
        ),
    ),
    black: #000,
   
) !default;
```

Is there a way to remove the whole map content? So a user can start without the unwanted colors if he dosent need them? I know how to delete a single map item if the name is known, but i dont want to remove all items manually and sometimes the user dosent know the color names at all.

Thanks for any tips.

Kind regards
Marco

Comment: Why not look up how to build a color switcher and give them choices of colors instead of trying to deleting map variables? Kevin Powell on youtube has a few

Comment: Because its a part of a color and theming system and i want maximum flexibility.
but anyway, i think i found a solution. just overwrite the map with an empty string and then add the map stuff again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahhh it's super simple and totally obvious. Why I didn't realize this right away....

Just pass $colors an empty map and you're done.

```
$colors: ();
```